# Integral of the difference between a function and its floor

Tags: euler-mascheroni-constant

I know the following identity:
$$\int_1^\infty\left(-\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{\lfloor x\rfloor}\right)dx=\gamma$$
I have a function $f(b)=0.5\left(\sqrt{(N-b^2)}-b+1\right)$. Can a similar identity be derived for $$\int_1^\infty\left(-f(b)+\lfloor f(b)\rfloor\right)db$$

Thanks

Comment: $\sqrt{N-b^2}$ is complex for $b > \sqrt{N}$.